# Vi syntax highlighting for words followed by a parenthesis

Tags: regex, vi, syntax-highlighting

I want to change the color of a keyword that is followed by a left parenthesis in a .R file.

For instance, when I type `length()`, I want the word `length` to be highlighted (and not the parentheses), but when I type only `length` it won't receive any highlighting.

I would also like to specify the color of the highlighting based on the word. So `length()` and `function()` should result in different colors for `length` and `function`.

Edit: So far I'm using the following line in my r.vim syntax file to match a valid R object name followed by (:

```
syn match rFunction "\(\(\a\|[.][._\a]\)[._\a0-9]*\)\+\ *("
```

And this works fine, but I want to not highlight that `(` at the end, but rather have it be set to my default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a pattern to match, I think you could use an offset for the highlighting. From the [`vim` documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-pattern):

```
                    *:syn-pattern-offset*
The pattern can be followed by a character offset.  This can be used to
change the highlighted part
...
Example:
  :syn match String  /"[^"]*"/hs=s+1,he=e-1
    some "string" text
          ^^^^^^        highlighted
```

So I think this should do the job:

```
syn match rFunction "\(\(\a\|[.][._\a]\)[._\w]*\)\+\ *("he=e-1
```

You could also use lookaheads, which would be preferable, since it allows you to avoid having some elements enter the match:

```
syn match rFunction "\(\(\a\|[.][._\a]\)[._\w]*\)\+\ *[(]\@="
```

Comment: This does work, except that now I have issues when matching open and close parentheses together. My syntax file uses regions to match ( ) together and the match on the `word(` now overrides matching a pair. I've used `syn region rFunction matchgroup=Function start="\(\(\a\|[.][._\a]\)[._\w]*\)\+\ *(" matchgroup=Function end=")" transparent` but this makes the ( ) the color of the Function group, when I'd rather have it be the Delimiter group.

Comment: @mickwar I think `vim` syntax patterns support lookaheads, so instead of including the `(` in the pattern directly, add it as a positive lookahead. Something like: `"\(\(\a\|[.][._\a]\)[._\w]*\)\+\ *\\[\(]\@="he=e-1`

Comment: Removing some of the escape characters gave me the match properly: `syn match rFunction "\(\(\a\|[.][._\a]\)[._\w]*\)\+\ *[(]\@="`. This works great, thanks!

Comment: @mickwar ah, sorry about those. Copy-paste artifact.